# File not found error in ios 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am trying to add the files in my app.
If I tries to add folder having my files in side of that then getting file not found exception.
But if tries to add files without that folder then I am able to run the app without any error.

But How I can add folder having my all files in side of it directly in ios 5.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes. I will post the answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on your App in groups and files section, Select **Add files to "your app"....**

Once you do that, select folder you want to add and select "**Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)**" as shown in screenshot below.

**Note**:  **Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)** is to be selected only if the files are physically in some other folder and not the application bundle or application folder.

[image]

Now you will be able to add the folder and reference it properly.

Hope this helps.